# Dynamic WHERE condition when calling SQL from VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, select

In Excel I have a column of IDs. I would like to SELECT values from a table conditional on the values in the ID column. So far I've got this, where ws.Cells(i,10) refers to the values of each of the rows in column K.

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
    "ODBC;DSN=xxxx;Description=xxxxx;UID=xxx;APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;WSID=xxx" _
    ), Array("56;DATABASE=xxx;Trusted_Connection=Yes")), Destination:=Range( _
    "$M$3")).QueryTable        

    For i = 1 To 691
    sText = "SELECT Instrument.ID, Instrument.MATURITY FROM xxxx.dbo.Instrument Instrument WHERE Instrument.ID=" & ws.Cells(i, 10).Value & ""
    .CommandText = Array(sText)
    Next

End With
```

I get an error "424" on the row sText, error message "Object required".

I also have a hunch this is not the best way to do this. There has to be a simpler setup to run a SQL with WHERE conditions from a column.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I believe Excel may have a built-in connection, or at least a plugin, that will let Excel directly talk to a database.  I'd also be careful about concatenating strings - SQL injection is nasty.

Comment: Is your database SQL Server? If so, OpenRowset may suit. It would allow you to pull data from both the SQL database and Excel at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive that iDevlop is correct - you haven't defined your variable **ws**, which results in the "Object Required" error message.

In any event, you might like this solution better:

```
Dim IDs as String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
IDs = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
           ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 10), ws.Cells(691, 10))), ",")
.CommandText = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Instrument.ID in (" + IDs + ")"
```

No loop necessary.